# Controlling vertical space between block-level elements

Tags: css

I've read a few articles on vertical rhythm and web typography but there's an aspect that's never really discussed.

I prefer having much space (or no extra margin/padding) between a headline and it's first paragraph as this visually groups the headline with it's content much better.

I've tried removing `margin-bottom` from headlines but because of margin collapse, the `margin-top` on paragraphs or ul's gets used - so you end up with the same vertical space between the headline and it's content.

Is there a way to say to the browser that the first paragraph shouldn't have any margin between it and it's headline?

`.main p:first-child` doesn't work because the browser doesn't look for the first instance of a p (unless it is the very first item which it won't be because there's always a headline before it).

Hope that makes sense - any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this selector then :

```
.headline + p {
   /*Styles to remove*/
   margin-top:0;
}
```

With this you select any `p` that is right after a `headline`

Comment: Cheers, I hadn't seen that selector and after refactoring the type styles so the selector would take effect, it worked great - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic of negative margin-bottom on your header.

```
h1 {
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}
```